# Password reset throws "An Exception was raised while creating "Laminas\Mail\Protocol\Smtp\Auth\Login" no instance returned

Tags: magento2.3.5

I am resetting the password of magento 2.3 admin account (backend) and I get the exception saying "An Exception was raised while creating "Laminas\Mail\Protocol\Smtp\Auth\Login" no instance returned"

But password gets updated to new password

Can anyone help me to resolve this exception

Comment: have you tried deleting generated folder and running indexer:reindex

Comment: Check your SMTP configuration.

Comment: @AsadUllah I tried deleting generated folder and reindexing but it did not worked

Comment: does your login class exists?@LegredVaz

Comment: @AsadUllah Yes Login class does exist

Comment: were you able to solve it ? I'm facing same error for every email

Comment: Yes I updated my SMTP configuration

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SMTP Configurations were wrong. I updated SMTP configuration